# How can I configure logrotate to SCP multiple log files

Tags: mysql, logrotate

I would like to copy multiple files form logrotate, so I try this :

```
/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    create 640 mysql adm
    compress
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
            scp /var/log/mysql.log root@w.x.y.z:/var/log/mysql/mysql-`date -d "$D" '+%d'`-`date -d "$D" '+%m'`.txt
            scp /var/log/mysql/error.log root@w.x.y.z:/var/log/mysql/error-`date -d "$D" '+%d'`-`date -d "$D" '+%m'`.txt
    endscript
    postrotate
            test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin || exit 0
            # If this fails, check debian.conf!
            MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"
            if [ -z "`$MYADMIN ping 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
              # Really no mysqld or rather a missing debian-sys-maint user?
              # If this occurs and is not a error please report a bug.
              #if ps cax | grep -q mysqld; then
              if killall -q -s0 -umysql mysqld; then
                exit 1
              fi
            else
              $MYADMIN flush-logs
            fi
    endscript
}
```

But all files copied are empty. I don't have this issue with nginx logrotate. I suppose it's because they are multiple entries for rotation.

How can I get the current file (I suppose it's a loop for multiple files, maybe I am wrong) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that linux loop for each files if the option sharedscripts is not defined.

Variable $1 contains the actual current rotating file or list of the current rotating files if sharedscripts is defined.